# bash checking directory existence hanging when NFS mount goes down

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, nfs

I have a .bash_profile script that sets up some aliases for me based on directory existence:

```
if [ -d  /home/user/games ] ; then
  alias cdgames='cd /home/user/games'
fi
```

One of these directory is on an NFS mount - if the filer becomes unresponsive `su - user` will hang on this line in .bash_profile.

Is there any way to check existence of a directory in bash without causing a hang if the directory is mounted to an unresponsive filer?

Comment: Just an idea: maybe you can create an alias everytime, and the alias will check the directory: `alias cdgames='if grep /home/user/games /etc/mtab; then cd /home/user/games ; else echo "Directory not changed: not mounted"; fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the folder should appear as a mount device in /etc/mtab you can try something like this

```
if grep -q '/home/user/games' /etc/mtab ; then 
    alias cdgames='cd /home/user/games'
fi
```

This approach is a bit rude but it works for most of the situations.

Comment: Brilliant - I replaced the code with:

`if grep '/home/user/games' /etc/mtab 1>/dev/null; then 

    alias cdgames='cd /home/user/games'

elif [ -d '/home/user/games ] ; then

    alias cdgames = 'cd /home/user/games'

fi`

Comment: DRY: `if grep '/home/user/games' /etc/mtab 1>/dev/null || [ -d '/home/user/games' ] ; then alias cdgames = 'cd /home/user/games' fi`

Comment: I edit my answer to add the -q parameter. It avoids print the result, and its cleaner that pipe to /dev/null